# Get all possible subsets from a set of distinct integers using OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, homework

An assignment at school required me to write a program for this task:

> 1. Create a `class` and define two methods in the class.
> 2. Method `f1` is used to pass an empty list and the sorted list is taken from the user to method `f2`.
> 3. Method `f2` is used to compute all possible subsets of the list.
> 4. Then the result is returned from the function and printed.
> 5. Exit

Here is my solution to this task, using Python:

```
class sub:  
    def f1(self, s1):  
        return self.f2([], sorted(s1))  

    def f2(self, current, s1):  
        if s1:  
            return self.f2(current, s1[1:]) + self.f2(current + [s1[0]], s1[1:])  
        return [current]  
a = []
n = int(input("Enter number of elements of list: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    b = int(input("Enter element: "))
    a.append(b)
print ("Subsets: ")
print (sub().f1(a))
```

NOTE - Method `f2` is a recursive function.

Here are some example inputs and outputs:

```
Enter number of elements of list: 2
Enter element: 4
Enter element: 5
Subsets: 
[[], [5], [4], [4, 5]]

Enter number of elements of list: 4
Enter element: 3
Enter element: 5
Enter element: 7
Enter element: 28
Subsets: 
[[], [28], [7], [7, 28], [5], [5, 28], [5, 7], [5, 7, 28], [3], [3, 28], [3, 7], [3, 7, 28], [3, 5], [3, 5, 28], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7, 28]
```

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if you've felt passed over when I removed the performance tag. Performance is **not** an issue in your case, this tag is meant for code where the runtime is critical and/or should be reduced.

Comment: @AlexV - Ohh... Now I know. Removed it. Thank you :)

Comment: Just so that you've heard about it: There is a [tag wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/performance/info) for each tag (I guess - have not checked them all) describing precisely what the tag is about.

Comment: Never do this in production code. A function is [more than sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1482308/1394393). OOP is just clutter for generating a power set. Be aware that whatever you got this from is teaching you un-Pythonic patterns and going against the normal idioms of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I.` This chunk of code:

```
a = []
n = int(input("Enter number of elements of list: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    b = int(input("Enter element: "))
    a.append(b)
```

is mostly C-like (or Pascal-like etc). You can replace it with more Pythonic:

`a = input('Enter elements splitted by ":" ').split(' ')`

`II.` Here:

`print (sub().f1(a))`

You are creating a `sub` instance within the `print` function. It is a bad idea because it will disappear after print. You should create it before you print something (and, yes, classes names in Python are in CamelCase):

```
waka = Sub()
print(waka.f1(a))
```

`III.` I prefer to create `__init__()` function each time I create a class. It is not really necessary but in most cases, it is the first one is creating in the new class:

```
class Sub(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

`IV.` If it is your homework you should do with recursion, the code is pretty OK. In another case, I recommend you to use Python [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module (you should avoid recursion as much as possible):

```
    def f2(self, current, s1):  
        return [
            e
            for e in itertools.chain.from_iterable([
                [sorted(l) for l in itertools.combinations(s1, length)]
                for length in range(1, len(s1))
            ])
        ]
```

So here is the result code for recursion version:

```
class Sub(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f1(self, s1):  
        return self.f2([], sorted(s1))  

    def f2(self, current, s1):  
        if s1:  
            return self.f2(current, s1[1:]) + self.f2(current + [s1[0]], s1[1:])  
        return [current]

a = input('Enter elements splitted by " ": ').split(' ')
waka = Sub()
print(waka.f1(a))
```

Comment: Upvoted! Thanks for the very detailed response! Some really good stuff in here!

Comment: I don't think the outer `[]` are needed within the `chain.from_iterable`, and `list(...)` instrad of `[e for e in... ]`