# Python program to find the substring with concatenation of all words

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, object-oriented, programming-challenge

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/substring-with-concatenation-of-all-words/description/):

> *You are given a string, **S**, and a list of words, **L** that are all of the same lengths. Find all starting indices of substring(s) in **S** that is a concatenation of each word in **L** exactly once and without any intervening characters.*

Here is my solution to the problem:

```
class Solution:

    def __init__(self, S, L):
        self.S = S
        self.L = L

    def findSubstring(self, S, L):    
        res = []      # result list
        num = len(L)  # length of the str list 
        ls = len(S)
        if num == 0:
            return []
        str_len = len(L[0]) # length of each str

        #creating the map: counting the occurrence of each string

        map_str = dict((x,L.count(x)) for x in set(L))
        i = 0
        while i + num * str_len - 1 < ls:
            map_str2 = {}
            j = 0
            while j < num:
                subs = S[i + j * str_len:i + j * str_len + str_len ]
                if not subs in map_str:
                    break
                else:
                    map_str2[subs] = map_str2.get(subs, 0) + 1
                    if map_str2[subs]>map_str[subs]:
                        break
                    j = j + 1
            if j == num:
                res.append(i)
            i = i + 1

        return res

S = "barfoothefoobarman"
L = ["bar","foo"]

index = Solution(S, L)
print(index.findSubstring(S, L))
```

Here are some example inputs/outputs:

```
S = "barfoothefoobarman"

L = ["bar", "foo"]

>>> [0, 9]

-------------------------------------------------------------------

S = "lingmindraboofooowingdingbarrwingmonkeypoundcake"

L = ["fooo", "barr", "wing", "ding", "wing"]

>>> [13]
```

So I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told in [another](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220730/201170) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220645/201170), your code is very C/C++ styled, it is not Pythonic. Try to avoid manual iteration with indices as much as possible. Python has an enormous standard library that contains many useful modules. I already recommended you an [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools) module. It contains pair of dozens generic functions to work with iterators. One of them - [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations) - do 90% of your work:

> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
>
> `permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC`
>
> `permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210`

For list L, it returns all possible permutations iterator. If we will [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) each permutation, we will get the needed search substring.

But next we will have a problem. Python has no built-in function or easy method to find indices of all found substrings in the string (it is strange, I hope they will add it to future Python versions). So you have to do it manually. You can run `string.find(substring)` in the loop and, after each found substring, to shorten the search range.

Here is the code for my solution:

```
from itertools import permutations


class Solution(object):
    """
    Leetcode-XXXXX solution
    """

    def find_chained_substrings(self, S, L):
        result = []
        for perm in permutations(L):
            chained_string = ''.join(perm)
            i = S.find(chained_string)
            while i != -1:
                result.append((i, perm))
                i = S[i+len(chained_string):].find(chained_string)
        return result

    
waka = 'foobarwakatttpingpong-ongpingpt'
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'waka']
lst2 = ['t', 'pingp', 'ong']
S = Solution()
S.find_chained_substrings(waka, lst2)
```

It will return:

`[(12, ('t', 'pingp', 'ong')), (22, ('ong', 'pingp', 't'))]`

**Note**, that your Leetcode task needs only indices. I construct index-substring tuple for readability and simplier testing. If you want to make a Leetcode solution, replace this string:

`result.append((i, perm))`

with this:

`result.append(i)`

---

P.S. I strongly recommend you to read the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) documentation. It will greatly improve your Python programming skill and will shift you from the C/C++ish style to Pythonic style.